# Searching multiple table columns

Tags: javascript

I have the below code which does a good job in searching for matches in one specific table column, but it would be nice if I could get it to search all columns in the HTML table. I just don't know how I can modify the existing code to accomplish it. Any help would be appreciated!

I have isolated what part of this code deals with column selection - `td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` - but I don't know how to modify it to loop through all values in that array as it searches for a match.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="searchInput" onkeyup="tableSearch()" placeholder="Search for something ...">
```

JS

```
function tableSearch() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `some()` to check if any `td` in same `tr` is match the input text.

```js
const table = document.querySelector("#myTable");
const tableSearch = (e) => {
  let input, tds;
  input = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  table.querySelectorAll("tr").forEach(tr => {
    tds = [...tr.querySelectorAll("td")]
    if (tds.length !== 0) tr.style.display = tds.some(td => td.innerText.toUpperCase().includes(input)) ? '' : "none";
  });
}
document.querySelector("#searchInput").addEventListener('input', tableSearch);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Search for something ...">
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
    <th>c</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>bcd</td>
    <td>cde</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>abc</td>
    <td>def</td>
    <td>ghi</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>cba</td>
    <td>def</td>
    <td>ijk</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a second for-loop inside the first one that loops over each td element and checks each value. Right now you're only grabbing the first one of each row (`tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];` note the `[0]` at the end).

Something like this should do it:

```js
function tableSearch() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, x, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    tr[i].style.display = "none"; // hide by default
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (x = 0; x < td.length; x++) { // loop over each "td" within this row(tr)
      txtValue = td[x].textContent || td[x].innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
        break; // don't care about the rest of the columns on this row as it already found a match for us, so we can skip the rest.
      }
    }
  }
}
```